# Deploying same containers with different ENV variables in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have built a nodejs application which subscribes to Mosquitto MQTT Broker topic, and saves the incoming data to DB. I have also dockerized the app.

I need the app to run in a container, with its own environmental variables. i.e The different instance of an app write data to different destination. Ex. **instance1** app will have env variable **DEST=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres**  and **instance2** app will have env variable **DEST=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/postgres.**

I am not clear how to achieve this requirement with AWS ECS, not sure how port mapping will work. Whether I should create different task definition for each app instance, so that I have freedom to specify env variables there or create one task definition and create multiple services out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not clear how to achieve this requirement with AWS ECS, not sure
> how port mapping will work. Whether I should create different task
> definition for each app instance, so that I have freedom to specify
> env variables there or create one task definition and create multiple
> services out of it.

You can't specify environment variables at the service level. You would need to create separate task definitions.

Comment: Ok.

What about the port mapping ? My nodejs app is small, doesn't take heavy workload. I am planning to use one EC2 instance for all different variant of nodejs app. Now how my port mapping should be configured

Comment: The port mapping depends on the network mode you have configured in your tasks. What network mode are you using?

Comment: I am using AWSVPC

Comment: If you are using AWSVPC for the network mode, then each task gets its own ENI, separate from the ENI on the EC2 instance, and each ENI gets its own private IP address in the VPC. So there will be no port conflicts.